# mobile html site, do I need to use jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

So for the time being I will just be creating a mobile version of my app. Basic html/css/jquery sized to fit mobile screens...

Should I still be using jQuery Mobile for this or can I simply create as I would any webpage using jQuery overlays, tabs, etc...

Is there benefit to jQuery mobile vs standard jQuery in this case?
Or does it simply add "native mobile like" animations?

Comment: There are probably some kind of advantages for some but just as I don't use jQuery UI I don't use jQuery Mobile even while I use jQuery. You certainly don't **need** it.

Comment: This is kind of how I feel, I have always just stuck to jQuery for everything, but as I am no expert in this at all, I thought perhaps I am going about this all wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a trimmed down page in terms of visuals then you can accomplish what you want in CSS and don't need jQueryMobile. What jQM gives you are the great page transitions, list views, dialogs, etc. If you want your page to behave more like a mobile application then you want to use jQueryMobile.

Comment: I have taken a look at some of these transitions and dialogs which seem great in terms of animation, but they are also super styled. I would like to be able to control the design/styling as much as possible, how tied am I in this respect, should I choose to use jQueryMobile?

Comment: If you are comfortable with CSS then jQueryMobile makes it very easy to create your own themes and styles. You will still have the same basic page structures, but you can easily change the coloring, icons, backgrounds, etc.